# Javascript: using apply() method on object instance method fails

Tags: javascript, object, methods, dhtmlx

I need to use `apply()` or `call()` method on an object instance method of DHTMLX layout. The following works as expected:

```
A.setSkin('dhx_web');
```

However when using `apply()` an error is generated

```
A.setSkin.apply(undefined,['dhx_web']);


A.setSkin.call(undefined,'dhx_web');


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dhx_web' of undefined
```

Comment: That's `call`, not `apply`...

Comment: try another value instead of `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter should be specified. It will set the value of `this` inside the `setSkin` function.

```
A.setSkin.apply(A, ['dhx_web']);
A.setSkin.call(A, 'dhx_web');
```